# How to force spring's @ResponseBody to use xmlConvertor

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, jaxb

When I return a single object from a controller like this,

```
@ResponseBody 
public MyClass module(...) {
...
}
```

I get the xml output on the client and log shows like this,

> 2011-09-07 18:22:06,963 [qtp1409490836-27] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
>   - Written [com.domain.MyClass@4374820d] as "application/xhtml+xml"
>   using
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter@b4e1f3]

But If I use a list like this,

```
@ResponseBody 
public List<MyClass> module(...) {
...
}
```

It uses jsonConvertor and returns the json output.

> 2011-09-07 18:38:31,026 [qtp420370595-26] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
>   - Written [[com.domain.MyClass@654309f0]] as
>   "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@14419f80]

The MyClass is annotated with jaxb. In jersey I could say

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
```

How do I force spring to use the xmlconverter always?

Comment: What are you setting for the `Accept` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some bug that means you cannot return your class in a list. You need to create a new class to hold your list of objects and return that in the @ResponseBody. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ListHolder getFoos(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/xml");         
    List<Foo> foos = getFoos(); 
    ListHolder listHolder = new ListHolder();
    listHolder.setFoos(foos);
    return listHolder;
}
```

Annotate your ListHolder class with @XmlRootElement and if your have the jaxb jar or Java 6 then it should work.

Comment: Yep! this is what I have done finally. But the jersey does a beautiful thing. If a list<Foo> is returned it creats an additional <Foos> tag wrapping all the <Foo> tag.

Comment: I believe this is a JAXB requirement to need to wrap classes, see [annotating your classes in the jaxb documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.6/docs/ch03.html#annotating-your-classes).

Answer (score -1):

If Spring cant find a JSON convert it can't send JSON. Try to remove jackson.jar from the class path and it should default to XML through XStream for all request.

Comment: I can't remove any of the dependency jars.