# 406 Not Acceptable for List - REST

Tags: spring, list, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-406

I am trying to find a way instead of Wrapper class but I always get 406 Not Acceptable error. I searched online and tried many different ways but couldn't fix it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/getlist", headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Permission> getList(@RequestParam String userEmail) {         
    List<Permission> permissions = service.getPermissions(userEmail);

      return permissions;
}
```

And

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> userMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
userMap.add("userEmail", email_address);

// Prepare acceptable media type
List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

// Prepare header
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
HttpEntity<?> userEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(userMap, headers);

List<Permission> permissions = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/users/getlist", userEntity, List.class);
```

I also tried;

```
List<Permission> permissions = (List<Permission>) restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/users/getlist", userEntity, List.class);
```

So basically if I use a wrapper class with getter and setter, it works. But i need to create many wrapper classes. Do you have any idea to implement like this?

SOLUTION:

Worked adding no mediatype to the http entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that

```
headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json"
```

will require that your `Accept` header actually has the value `application/xml, application/json`. Your request doesn't.

You add a single acceptable media type.

```
List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
```

That will end up with a request header like

```
Accept: application/xml
```

Which won't match the `@RequestMapping` declared.

Instead, if you want the `headers` to match either `application/xml` or `application/json`, you can do

```
headers= {"Accept=application/xml", "Accept=application/json"}
```

or better yet

```
produces = {"application/xml", "application/json"}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried produces but still getting the 406 error. Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: @user3058742 Do you have Jackson on your classpath?

Comment: I have. When it is a single object, there is no problem. I couldn't figure out with collection.

Comment: @user3058742 Which Spring and Jackson versions are you using? I'm going to try to reproduce.

Comment: Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE , jackson 1.9.13 - Thank you !

Comment: @user3058742 Oh, I didn't realize you were trying with XML. You'll need to register a custom `Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter` I believe.

Comment: @user3058742 Or consider wrapping the `List` in a POJO annotated with JAXB annotations.

Comment: I don't know how to do, let me try it. Also do you suggest with any other way that could be better or easier?

Comment: @user3058742 One option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334557/how-to-force-springs-responsebody-to-use-xmlconvertor

Comment: Yes, i tried this option before and it worked. I need to work on list on many places so it is not going to be a good way to create a new class for all recent classes. Anyway, i will not have any other option if Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter not works. Thanks

Comment: @user3058742 Note that the `Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter` by itself doesn't work. You'll need to create a custom subclass.

Comment: I think i will go with wrapper class.. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh really ! when i send header like `HttpEntity<?> userEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(userMap, new HttpHeaders());` without `MediaTypes`, it works. Do you have a good explanation for that because I am not clear. Basically, the way I post is working without using mediatypes.

Comment: @user I believe, when you don't send an Accept header, all content types are accepted. If you look at your content, it should be JSON.

Comment: Yes it seems as you say. Thank you !